# Does a multiplication in c statement gives a different result when it is done in single step and when done in multiple steps?

Tags: c

If I do

```
sum2=(((p/2)%m)*((p+1)%m))%m;
sum2=(sum2 * (p%m))%m;
```

I get the right answer but if I do

```
sum2=((p%m)*(((p/2)%m)*((p+1)%m))%m)%m;
```

I get the wrong answer. What is the reason?
All variables are of unsigned long long integer type and m<=10000000.
PS:Question updated because of typo.

Comment: please provide the declaration of the variables. The type might affect the calculations

Comment: You have a typo in the first statement.

Comment: are you sure these two are equal?`((+1)%m))` is that right?

Comment: It would help to know the type of the variables and their *values*.

Comment: I have edited the question with the appropriate corrections.

Comment: Please give a specific example with values and the results.

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you a specific example as i submitted the code to an online judge and i don't know the test cases he used.

Comment: You didn't try testing yourself? You _can_ give the types... you _can_ conduct your own tests (negative numbers, positive/negative, zero, floating point values, very large/small numbers, etc...) and print the results so we can help see what might be going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum2=((p%m)*((((p/2)%m)*((p+1)%m))%m))%m;`
This should work for you.There was a problem with parentheses.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. `* ` and `/` and `%` have equal precendence but are done in left to right order.

Comment: Yup.The problem is solved.There was this parentheses problem.Thanks to all of u for your help.